# Java ODRPACK (or similar) Library

Tags: java, math, regression

I am after a java implementation of ORDPACK (like what SciPy does) or other similar regression algorithm which considers errors in X and Y.

I have looked through the nist javanumerics site for anything, however none of it is relevant.

At the very least I require a library that can do linear regression with errors in X and Y.

Anyone know of any?

Regards,
Inci

Answer (score 0):

The [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) machine learning package is quite nice and should provide you with everything you need.

Personally I like using R for anything statistics related.  You can use [JRI](http://rosuda.org/JRI/) to make calls to R in Java or [RServe](http://rosuda.org/Rserve/) to call R from Java over TCP/IP.

All packages will allow you to calculate linear regressions and much much more.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however neither of these allow for errors/uncertainties in the data points. I require something to take an input of 'X, Xerr, Y, Yerr' or something along those lines.